# How to find the error of all the counts within the Full Width Half Maximum (FWHM)?

Tags: experimental-physics, measurements, error-analysis, statistics, gamma-rays

We've been doing Gamma ray spectroscopy and have peaks from various sources. We'd use Poisson statistics, but obviously the detector doesn't have a resolution of zero, thus we are summing the counts over the Full Width Half Maximum. So should the error be just the square root of the sum of all counts?

(The individual error is the square root, and the error propagation formula requires to add the squares under a root)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *counting error* should be $\sqrt{N}$ where $N$ is the total number of counts in the range considered (here the FWHM). It is possible that there are other sources of error we need to be dealt with separately.

In particular if either the acceptance of the efficiency of the detector changes non-trivially over the range considered (rare but not unknown) those are additional problems.

Comment: Yeah the efficiency is different for each energy level. It roughly follows a Levy distribution. That is what we are actually trying to find.

Comment: The efficiency changing from peak to peak is very common, but changing enough to matter over the width a single peak is fairly rare for precision devices like germanium detectors. If you have  NaI detector I'd be more worried about that. The acceptance issue is similar: it can change significantly over the range of a typical detector but usually does not change much over the width of a peak.